# How to convert varchar into date time while performing SELECT?

Tags: sqlite

Following are the datetime values stored in a table as varchar. I want to convert them into datetime while using it in SELECT sql.

8/14/2012 7:52:32 AM

8/16/2012 3:34:22 AM

8/14/2012 9:04:03 AM

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite doesn't support a native datetime data type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:

You can get your output in the *format* you want with [strftime() or datetime()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).